# How can I do psql commands on server A if Server B has the connection to PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql, security, networking, amazon-ec2

**Server A [Linux] => Server B [Linux] => PostgreSQL**

How can I do psql commands on server A if Server B has the connection to PostgreSQL?

Comment: There is no "the connection".  PostgreSQL is a multiuser user system.  You can connect to it from A and B and C and D all at the same time.  So why don't you just connect from A to PostgreSQL?  There may be reasons, but without knowing what they are we don't know how to work around them.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue a remote command over something like SSH. `ssh USER@HOST 'COMMAND'`, where command is your normal psql command.